# Ubuntu completely changed layout by itself

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I'm new to Ubuntu and tried to hibernate my system with a command in terminal. This command `sudo systemctl hibernate`. My laptop then went to sleep mode and when I awoke it it was from thi:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Since then I cant return it to the previous state. What happened? How do I fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Your pictures appear to be of 1) Unity desktop and 2) some other desktop, maybe Gnome.   (although they don't appear to be of the same system, hmm) Log out and choose Unity desktop on login.

Comment: It was some kind of Cinammon layout. Thank you I fixed it thanks to you!

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Can you please post that as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your pictures appear to be of 1) Unity desktop and 2) some other desktop, maybe Gnome. (although they don't appear to be of the same system, hmm) Log out and choose Unity desktop on login.